# How to use append() and make output of loop into new list instead of print

Tags: python, list, text

I have a loop I'm using which works great that is:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines2):
    if "2. Primary Contact Person" in line:
        print(*lines[i:i+5], sep="\n")
```

Which gives me back contact information.  So far no issues.  But I now want to make the print out and append it into a new list instead of just printing it.

I tried

```
primary_contact = []

for i, line in enumerate(lines2):
    if "2. Primary Contact Person" in line:
        primary_contact.append(*lines[i:i+5], sep="\n")
```

But i get the following error:
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments

How would I get this to output to be added into a list?

Comment: Can you give an example of what `lines` look like? What the error says is that you cannot pass `sep="\n"` into the append command because it simply does not have it (unlike `print`)

Comment: Because it doesn't. Why would you need `sep="\n"` when _adding_ to the end of the list? You'll get distinct items that you can separate by a carriage return when you either try to write or display the data

Comment: How about primary_contact = ['\n'.join(lines[i:i+5]) for i, line in enumerate(lines2) if "2. Primary Contact Person" in line]

Comment: @DarrylG thanks that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using List Comprehension:

```
primary_contact = ['\n'.join(lines[i:i+5]) for i, line in enumerate(lines2) if "2. Primary Contact Person" in line]
```

The term:

```
'\n'.join(lines[i:i+5])
```

Generates a string equivalent to the earlier output

Answer (score 0):

Python's list.append method takes no additional named arguments. The method append only takes into argument the element which you would like to append to the end of the list. In your case I believe it would be:

primary_contact.append(line)

Depending on what the contents of the actual line looks like, as per your above example - a list slice maybe applicable depending on the actual string you wish to append.